# Deleting an instance of an object with a MANY_TO_MANY relationship without cascading fails

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-roo

I've got two classes (Students and Courses) which have a many-to-many-relationship. 
Instances of them can exist without the other one.
Therefore I removed the cascade-attribute in the JPA-annotation: @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Once I try to delete a Student I get this error-message.

**What am I doing wrong?**

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   delete: [com.Student#4]; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   delete: [com.Student#4]

This is the Hibernate-output:

> Hibernate: delete from student where id=? and version=? 2011-09-19
>   15:25:10,317 [http-8080-3] ERROR
>   org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot delete or update a
>   parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`database`.`student_course`, CONSTRAINT `FKF8A06F72970A31AF` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`students`) REFERENCES `students` (`id`))

These are the relevant parts of both classes:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class Student{

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Course> courses= new HashSet<Course>();
}

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class Course {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    private Set<Student> students= new HashSet<Student>();
}
```

Comment: What is your intention? If you're _deleting_ the `Student`, you definitely want the `Set` in all `Course`s to be updated, correct? Try reinstating the cascade, but using `CascadeType.REMOVE`

Comment: Can you try clearing the courses collection before deleting the student. I don't think cascade will help here - cascade is for deleting the course when student is deleted. In your case what is causing the problem is the rows in the mapping table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest adding a `detachFromCourses()` method to your `Student`, which iterates over the `courses`, removing `this`. You'd call that just before deleting a `Student`. But that's ugly and it doesn't fit very well with Spring Roo.

May I suggest looking into creating a [JPA Entity Listener](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event) hooked up to the `@PreRemove` JPA event? Then you can keep your domain model and your controllers free of database-specific stuff. Your Entity Listener could then just do:

```
@PreRemove
void onPreRemove(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Student) {
        // Remove all the course references to this Student
        Student s = (Student) o;
        for (Course c : s.getCourses()) {
            c.getStudents().remove(s);
        }
    }
}
```